# Observable not update list when attribute change

Tags: ios, arrays, list, observable, swiftui

I'm working with SwiftUI on list to show object array and using ObservableObject to track the change of the object. if I change the array by adding or removing the list will change automatically.

But if I change change the attribute of the object. The list will not update.

Any suggest to update the List even if the attribute got update or anyway to force the List to update.

```
 List(self.carService.partList){ part in
     RowList(part:part)
 }
```

Comment: If you add your `ObservableObject` and the view struct the list is contained within, we'll be able to answer your question more effectively.

Comment: show your changing attribute code pls

Answer (score 0):

Push to the main thread? Perhaps the update is occurring, just not listed properly because of a threading mis-match

Comment: any change I make it under ```DispatchQueue.main.async ```

Comment: like I said if I add or remove any member of array it work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show more code to solve your problem.

In most situations the ObservedObject is not updating because of a invalid use of the properties. To make sure you want to tell the Object that the data has changed, we can tell the Object to notify the view.
Example given on how to work with the ObservedObject and Published property.

```
import Combine
import SwiftUI

class A: ObservableObject {
    @Published var id: String = ""
    @Published var value: String = ""
}

struct Example: View {

    @ObservedObject var obj: A

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.obj.value = "Hi im changed"
            self.obj.objectWillChange.send()
        }) {
            Text("Change me")
        }
    }
}
```

To notify the view the data changed, take note of the line:

```
self.obj.objectWillChange.send()
```

Hope this works, goodluck!